# notepad++ run plugin within macro

Tags: notepad++

I want to write a macro that fetches some text from a log file. The macro serach for some begin and end text (xml tags) and selects the text in between them. It copies this text to e new file.

And then I want to format it xml style so I call plugin 'xml tools'->'pretty print' and choose from menu 'language'-> 'XML'

But I want to include these 2 last steps into my macro. So that I only have to press one key combination, in stead of 3.
Is it possible? When recording and saving macro he ignores the 2 actions I do in the menu.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used your specific plugin, but you can usually assign keyboard shortcuts to plugin commands (Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Plugin commands). So if you do that, you should be able to register the shortcut key press in your macro.

Comment: the 'pretty print' plugin is already mapped to ctrl-alt-shift-b and it is not picked up in any macro recording.